# regexpr in PHP for capture all img ID

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem creating regexpr for capture all IDs from tags imgs. i have a code:

```
#<span><img (id=\"([^"]*)\").*><\/span>#
```

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/aN0uO0/3

only capture ID from first tag IMG.
Thanks.

Comment: Hover over that question mark to the right of the regex input;

Comment: You'll probably be better off using a parser unless the format is consistent. If other attributes are present between `img` and `id` the `id` will not be found with this regex.

Comment: Looks like you're attempting to use regex on HTML. [Obligatory warning.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are not searching `globally`, to enable that enter **g** on the right text field ( after the right **/** mark ).

If you are using `preg_match` in php, use `preg_match_all` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're eager to use a regex at all, you might get along with:

```
<img[^>]*?id=(['"])(.+?)\1
```

You'll find the id in the second group (`$2`). However, if you have a `>` somewhere in an attribute (which is totally valid in `HTML`), the regex won't work as expected. In `PHP` code this would be:

```
$regex = '~<img[^>]*?id=([\'"])(.+?)\1~';
$string = 'your_string_here';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

See [an example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aN0uO0/8).
*Hint: It's almost always better to use a parser, e.g. `SimpleXML` or `DomDocument`.*